# How to recognise that the dictionary has no known value for the input provided and not just cause error (KeyError) Python 3.6

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using a Python dictionary to read DNA bases into codons however want the program to recognise if nonsense is inputted into this. Currently all that happens is there is a key error when using something like

"codon += cod[F[x]]"

Is there a way to search the string of bases (AGCTATATCAT) (for example) for strings not found in the dictionary? For example if other characters that aren't ACGT were in it how would I detect this?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming `F` is the `dict` in question, `x in F`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if all characters in a string are in a given `set` by doing the following:

```
if set(string).difference(set("AGCT")):
    # There are characters other then 'AGCT' in string
else:
    # All characters in the string are one of "AGCT"
```

Comment: Thanks this was the tidiest solution and worked great. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This could trigger on a correct sequence if it did not contain one of the 4 characters. For however for long strings this is probably not an issue.

Comment: @ktzr Nope. It will not trigger. `a.diffrence(b)`: Only elements in a that are not in b will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to validate that every char in a string is a valid base is to use the [`set.issuperset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issuperset) method. Eg,

```
valid_bases = set('ACGT')

for s in ('AGCTAT', 'ATCQAT'):
    print(s, valid_bases.issuperset(s))
```

**output**

```
AGCTAT True
ATCQAT False
```

If you wish to identify the illegal chars, you can use [set difference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference):

```
valid_bases = set('ACGT')

for s in ('AGCTAT', 'ATCQAT', 'ATCQAZT'):
    bad = set(s) - valid_bases
    print(s, bad or "ok")
```

**output**

```
AGCTAT ok
ATCQAT {'Q'}
ATCQAZT {'Z', 'Q'}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll use the set difference to add output of identifying the illegal characters. Thanks for the help